# Is $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor -x$ a Darboux function?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor -x$

My book claims this function is not a [Darboux function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_function).

Is this true ? I cannot find a counterexample to prove that this is not a Darboux function.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Yes, your book is right.

Comment: @Gae.S. ok. Could you also explain why please ?

Comment: Personally, I won't.

Comment: Did you try to plot the function? What happens in a small neighborhood of $x=0$ (or any integer)?

Comment: Gae is too important to answer your question, but his time isn't *so* important that he can't set some aside to let you know just how important it is.

Comment: @JohnSamples No, I do use time for unimportant things (like MSE) but I don't do things that I find boring in that specific moment (allegedly important or otherwise) such as detailing an answer to this question. I've been asked if I would do that, and I answered the truth.

Comment: No, then you just wouldn't have answered it.  You went out of your way to let 'em know, though.  Are we pretending to be social idiots or something, give me a break.  If u weren't salty you wouldn't have downvoted my answer haha, WHAT a child.

Comment: @JohnSamples I haven't downvoted anything. I could prove it by downvoting the question and your answer, but that would be a bit excessive, I think.

Comment: Fiiiine, if you say so.  I upvoted your comment for being obnoxious myself haha.  But please be nicer to the n00bz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the interval $(\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ the image of your function is equivalently $-x$ away from $1$ and $f(1) = 0$.  Thus the image of this interval under $f$ is $(-1, -\frac{1}{2}) \cup \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ which is not connected, but the interval $(\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ is connected, contradicting the Darboux property.

Comment: There's a cool open problem on Darboux functions that I'd like to pump.  I believe I've solved the plane case, but trying to generalize first.  MSE/MO hero Taras Banakh published a paper with interesting partial results as a result of the question; it's linked in the thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235893/does-there-exist-a-bijection-of-mathbbrn-to-itself-such-that-the-forward-m

Answer (score 0):

$f(\frac34)=-\frac34$ while $f(1)=0$. But the intermediate value $-\frac12$ is not assumed on $(-\frac34,1)$.